# Saving JPanel Graphics

Tags: java, swing

I'm not quite sure exactly how Graphics work in Java so I having trouble debugging my problem.
I have a Class MyFrame Extends JPanel. Now I do some drawing on MyFrame save and save me properties about that certain frame then add it an ArrayList collection of MyFrames. Later on I want to recall the properties a certain instance of MyFrame and repaint that frame on the screen. Having the the graphic of frame show up again is what I am having trouble with.

Here is a quick bit of code that will demonstrate my problem.

```
public class MyFrame extends JPanel{
private int property;
private int x;
private int y;

public MyFrame(int xp, int yp){
x = xp;
y = yp;
}

@override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
g.fillRect(x,y,5,5);
}
public void setProperty(int p){
property = p;
}
}

public class MainClass() extends JPanel{
private ArrayList<MyFrame> frames = new ArrayList<MyFrame>;
private MyFrame currentFrame = new MyFrame();

public void addFrame(int x, int y){
this.remove(currentFrame);
currentFrame = new MyFrame();
this.add(currentFrame);
frames.add(currentFrame);
}

public void setFrame(int frame){
this.remove(currentFrame);
currentFrame = frames.get(frame);
this.add(currentFrame);
}

}
```

Summary:
I'd like the panel to display the correct frame when setFrame is called. currently when I do this set frame will be blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be swapping JPanels in and out of another JPanel, and when doing this, you must take into consideration the layout used by the container-JPanel and you would need to call revalidate and repaint on the container-JPanel after the swap.

But rather than mess with all of this, why not go the easy route by just swaping JPanels or perhaps JLabels with ImageIcons holding an image using a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: What is the maximum number of "Cards" that you can place into a CardLayout. The purpose of this app is to design frame by frame animations thats will eventually be played to a 10x10 RGB LED board that I am building. Since this is going to be potentially large animations there will certainly be a few hundred frames

Comment: I think that it depends on what type of data structure that the CardLayout uses to store references to its cards. Given the time it was built, I'm guessing it uses a Vector, and a Vector can hold many items. But if your display is only changing simulated LED lights, then you may only need one JPanel and just change what is drawn in it. I don't know without more information though.

Comment: Originally I tried to redraw on the same frame everytime however I was having trouble repainting the frame everytime. My specific problem was that I would call repaint to repaint each LED one by one but for some reason the repaint method would never call the my paintComponents method. I abandoned that for this new structure. If there is an easy way to repaint it all I can easily switch back to the old structure. It seems to me that the orignally way I was doing it is the best option

Comment: @user90: please go into greater detail just what you're trying to achieve from a **user's point of view**, not the coding steps you've taken to try to achieve this.

Comment: The purpose of the UI is to allow the user to draw an animation frame-by-frame by setting the color of each LED light in a 2d array (10x10). In the end the animation will be written to a microcontroller that will play the animation on the actual LEDS. For each LED on each frame the RGB value needs to be save. Also the duration of each frame needs to be saved.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider adding some states, an enum data member, to a single JPanel and ask it to switch from one state to another, then call its repaint method and, in its paintComponent overriden method, draw some graphics according to its state.

Your architecture (as enhance by @Hovercraft Full of Eels is also good, even better if the draw methods vary quite a lot and have very different purposes. However, my proposal could lay to a faster app, and could allow other fatures such as transition between states, shared double buffer, variable/code reuse in case graphics are close.

What is your app doing ?

Regards,
 Stéphane